# Remove old selected value from select2 list

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select with one of the options disabled (it disables/enables dinamically while a user clicks on another fields of form, adding the "disabled" attribute with jquery):

```
<select style="width:50%;" name="custom">
<option value="0" disabled>ND</option>
<option value="1">Alex Burn</option>
<option value="2">Tom Johnes</option>
<option value="3">Serhio Aguero</option>
<option value="4">Eugeny Petrosyan</option>
<option value="5">Mark Twen</option>
<option value="6">Jack Sparrow</option>
<option value="7">Luci Night</option>
<option value="8">Silvia Rodger</option>
<option value="9">Marko Roys</option>
<option value="10">Voldemar Fermer</option>
</select>
```

For some reason i have to make first option of this select as selected, and i can't modify this part of code:

```
$("[name='custom']").select2();
$("[name='custom']").val($("[name='custom'] option:first").val());
$("[name='custom']").select2("val", $("[name='custom'] option:first").val());
```

I don't want to see disabled option in my select2 list, and i use some css to hide it:

```
.select2-results__option[aria-disabled="true"] {
        display: none;
    }
```

It hides from select2 list, but... still displays as selected value. How can i avoid displaying it also as selected value?

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/y1tsh8ka/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
$("[name='custom']").select2();
$("[name='custom']").val($("[name='custom'] option:first").val());
$("[name='custom']").select2("val", $("[name='custom'] option:not([disabled]):first").val());
```

Instead of selecting the first value, it selects the first value that is not disabled

Comment: Thank you, man, but it does not suit me well, cause this part of code goes before the option becomes disabled/enabled/disabled again and so on

Comment: Ok. So you want to add this line of code in the event that enables/disables the options. So i would first check if the selected value is disabled and if so, then run this line of code

Comment: It should be like this 
if($('[name='custom']').find(":selected").prop('disabled')){
    $("[name='custom']").select2("val", $("[name='custom'] option:not([disabled]):first").val());
}

Comment: Updated fiddle with you modification, to see that it is not workin in my particular case: https://jsfiddle.net/jco4538z/1/

Comment: wow, you are right about pushing this modified line inside the event that disables options. Seems that this final fiddle is working :) https://jsfiddle.net/jco4538z/2/

Comment: Well, just want to add that it is better to use an expression like :

$("[name='custom2']").select2().val($("[name='custom'] option:not([disabled]):first").val()).trigger("change"); in a new versions of jquery, that goes from v4.0